# Apache camel - How to retrieve Endpoint URIs for a given Component

Tags: apache-camel

I use Apache Camel 2.20x.
A camel component can be developed with a uri scheme for example "sample-component". Now the Endpoint of this component can actually extend an existing Endpoint say SQL which has uri syntax as "sql:<select query">.

Now I am listening to camel Exchange event (ExchangeSentEvent) When I retrive the uri from the event I get "sql:<select query">. But what I want is to get "sample-component". How can we achieve that. In simple terms following is the ask
How can we get all Endpoint uri schemes for a camel component.

Thanks in advance
Gk

Answer (score 0):

ComponentName+Endpoint . You can see all the uri that the component will take. All camel components are named this way.There may be exceptions. also if u use intellij idea apache camel plugin it  show  .

examples

HttpEndpoint
TimerEndpoint
SedaEndpoint
DirectEndpoint

You can also find the consumer and producer classes of these components as follows.

HtppProducer if support HttpConsumer ..

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the details. But may be I was not clear on the question. My requirement is to get the "uri" base for example HttpEndpoint will has "ahc". During the message processing, I am listening to the ExchangeSentEvent, I want maintain some "allowed list" for which I want to process the event. Now to create this list, I need all the "uri" schemes used in a camel component. One camel component.